# Java: Automatic login into windows and linux

Tags: java, windows, unix, authentication

How I can check user credentials for local computer? 
For example, I have this strings:
Username: user
Password: pwd.

Scenario: Trying to login into windows or linux. if user user/pwd exist, method should return "true".

I can't use LDAP or databases, but I need use only local credentials...

This is possible?
and... if it's possible, should provide for the application with the appropriate rights

Comment: You want a Java application to log into Windows/Linux? Or do you want to access some resources which are provided by a Windows/Linux server and needs authentication?

Comment: should be checked credentials in Windows, Linux and *BSD. see updated question for @AlexR

Comment: Ok, I use JNA (https://github.com/twall/jna) for local machine, SpringLdap for AD, and Jaas. Thanks, AlexR and Dalshim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use [JAAS Login utility](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/tutorials/LoginSample.html) with  [JAAS Authentication](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/tutorials/AcnOnly.html) and J[AAS Authorization](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/tutorials/AcnAndAzn.html).

Seems to be doing what you want (if I understood your question well).

Answer (score 0):

The "right" way to do this is try to login using these credentials. You cannot get the credentials from OS because they are event not stored there in clear text.

You have a lot of ways to login to machine. On linux you can use SSH. Use one of available Java SSH libraries (e.g. Jsh). Send your credentials and see if you an login. The same is for windows but there you can use WMI. The following WMI libraries are recommended: JaWin, Jintegra, Jinterop.

Probably Jinterop is the best choice because it is free and is pure java implementation, so it is cross-platform by definition: you can run on linux and login to remote windows machine. Jintegra is the same but not free. JaWin is a JNI wrapper, so the application has to run on windows.

Comment: Ok, and how i can check credentials into local machine (not in domain, for domain-oriented parts of the application I used LDAP; for simple network I trying to use your responce, thanks)?
Java application has a userName and password. I should to check existence of the user. if this user exist (and logined now), this userName and password should be used for distribution rights to the code execution.